# Django rest framework + multiple database + POST data

Tags: sql-server, django, post, django-rest-framework

I'm preparing API and I'm using multiple database ("oracle" and "sqlserver").

I want to POST data (json) into sqlserver.

Here is part of my code.

models.py  (every table is in sqlserver database)

```
class QtOfferParam(models.Model):
    ext_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    dealer_code = models.CharField(max_length=10, db_column="dealer_code")
    dealer_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, db_column="dealer_name")
    dealer_user = models.CharField(max_length=30, db_column="dealer_user")

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'ZZ_QT_OFFER_PARAM'

class QtParameterValues(models.Model):
    ext_id = models.ForeignKey(QtOfferParam, to_field="ext_id", db_column="ext_id", on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="parameterValues", primary_key=True)
    parameter = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, db_column="parameter")
    value_p = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, db_column="value_p")

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'ZZ_QT_PARAMETER_VALUE'

class QtOptions(models.Model):
    ext_id = models.ForeignKey(QtOfferParam, to_field="ext_id", db_column="ext_id", on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="options", primary_key=True)
    f_amount = models.FloatField(db_column="FINANCED_AMOUNT")
    installment_amount = models.FloatField(db_column="INSTALLMENT_AMOUNT")
    total_amount = models.FloatField(db_column="TOTAL_AMOUNT")
    total_amount_in_percentage = models.FloatField(db_column="TOTAL_AMOUNT_IN_PERCENTAGE")

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'ZZ_QT_OPTIONS'
```

serializers.py  (i added " **using='sqlserver'** ")

```
class ReqSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    dealer = DealerField(source='*')
    parameterValues = ParametersSgSerializer(many=True)
    options = OptionsSgSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = QtOfferParam
        fields = ['ext_id', 'dealer', 'parameterValues', 'options']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        parameters_data = validated_data.pop('parameterValues')
        options_data = validated_data.pop('options')
        req_id = QtOfferParam.objects.using('sqlserver').create(**validated_data)

        for parameters_data in parameters_data:
            parameters_data['ext_id'] = req_id
            QtParameterValues.objects.using('sqlserver').create(**parameters_data)

        for options_data in options_data:
            options_data['ext_id'] = req_id
            QtOptions.objects.using('sqlserver').create(**options_data)

        return req_id
```

views.py

```
class testView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = QtOfferParam.objects.using('sqlserver').all()
    serializer_class = ReqSerializer
```

when I GET data everything is OK. The data are from sql server, but if I try POST new json i get error from oracle database:

ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Where i need to add database to save data in sqlserver?

Comment: Where is the view handling the post request?

Comment: This is my all views : "class testView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = QtOfferParam.objects.using('sqlserver').all()
    serializer_class = ReqSerializer". When I was used tables in default database (oracle) I could POST data, everythin was OK. The problem starts when I change tables on this in SQLSERVER.

Comment: trying adding the using sqlserver

Comment: i added:
class testView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = QtOfferParam.objects.using('sqlserver').all()
    serializer_class = ReqSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        saveserialize = ReqSerializer(data=request.data)
        if saveserialize.is_valid():
            saveserialize.save(using='sqlserver')
            return Response(saveserialize.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response('error', status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

but it doesn't work

Comment: Returns the same error?

Comment: Yes. I don't have any idea.... :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229623/discussion-between-bartoszm-and-chymdy).